# Decomposition which is locally connected

Tags: gn.general-topology

It is possible construct a connected compact metric space $X$ and a continuous decomposition $\mathcal{G}$ of $X$ that satisfies:
1)$X/\mathcal{G}$ is locally connected.
2)If $M$ is a compact connected subset of $X$ and $M\cap G \neq \emptyset$ for some $G\in \mathcal{G}$, then $G\subset M$.
3)There exist $G\in\mathcal{G}$ and a compact connected subset $A$ of $X$ such that $A\not\subset D$ and $D\not\subset A$.

Thanks.

Comment: Something is wrong with your question. Your condition 2) implies that $\mathcal{G}$ contains only singleton sets, contradicting 3). 1) does not enter into it. What did you really mean? What is your motivation?